# Get stream URL in Kodi

Tags: python, live-streaming, kodi

I'm trying to figure out how to get the playing item URL (live TV).
I tried overriding Player but couldn't get the play method to be called and looked at jsonRPC calls, but couldn't find anything resembling what I want.
Is there a way to do it?

On another issue, I want to use ffmpeg and I noticed that Kodi already uses it. Is there a way I can reuse it or should I download the executable file myself?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to develop an addon/script - I need a method for finding out the URL currently played from XBMC builtins.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Player.Filename` infolabel like this:

```
filename = xbmc.getInfoLabel('Player.Filename')
```

Or you can use `Player.GetItem` JSON-RPC method.

**UPD**: This is a snippet from one of my addons:

```
def get_now_played():
"""
Get info about the currently played file via JSON-RPC.

:return: currently played item's data
:rtype: dict
"""
request = json.dumps({'jsonrpc': '2.0',
                      'method': 'Player.GetItem',
                      'params': {'playerid': 1,
                                 'properties': ['file', 'showtitle', 'season', 'episode']},
                      'id': '1'})
return json.loads(xbmc.executeJSONRPC(request))['result']['item']
```

As for ffmpeg libraries, they are linked with Kodi so I doubt that you can re-use them.

Comment: I've edited my question, thanks.
I'm trying to develop an addon - can't look at the log (although I did see that the URL is there)

Comment: I'm afraid that Player.Filename doesn't hold the URL for live-tv (I got "pvr.iptvsimple_1702591772.pvr")